# Makefile: the sequence of executing the makefile

Tags: makefile

Makefile:

```
foo: 
    @echo hello

%: force
    @echo foo

force:
    @echo force
```

If I typed `make foo', the output is:

```
force
foo
hello
```

So why not  `hello`

However, If I changed to this:

```
foo: 
    @echo hello

%:
    @echo foo

force:
    @echo force
```

It only outputs `hello`

Comment: If you want to gain a good understanding of the way make works then you should read [this](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/index.csp) instead of progressively adding more to your stack overflow questions.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because make has to track back through dependencies to make you a `foo`.

When you type `make foo`, make thinks you are asking it to make a file called `foo`. So as `foo` does not exist (assumption) it tries to work out how to make a `foo`. You made a wildcard rule `%` can be anything and since there is no better option make will try to use this rule to make a `foo`. To make `foo` now there is a dependency `force`, which needs to be executed before we can go about making `foo`. As a file `force` does not exist make determines it needs to execute the target to make `force`.

So we have reached the point where stuff starts to happen in terms of output. `force` executes which echos `force`, then the wildcard rule executes, which echos `foo` finally make believes its ready to create foo and the command is only to echo `hello`.

So it is actually in reverse order, from outermost dependency first to final target last.

When you take away `force` as a dependency of the wildcard rule then the wildcard rule will determine there is nothing to do to create force and so will not execute its body (echoing `foo`), but as `hello` does not exist it will execute the body of your `foo` target.

If you include something to make a file force in the force target (e.g. `touch force`) you will see now that `foo` and `hello` print, but not `force`.

You can see the steps make takes if you pass the flag `--debug=a` (all) to make on the command line.